# Recommended yoga positions to build to Bridge Pose?

Tags: yoga, beginners

What yoga positions are recommended to help a beginner build towards doing a full bridge pose/backbend (setu bandha sarvangasana)?

Comment: How far can you get into it so far?

Comment: Hmm... I had an answer, but I came to realize that it pertained to the gymnastic bridge pose, not the yoga one, so I've removed it.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - your question about how far I can get now was gold. I stumbled across exactly what I was looking for. Recapped it below.

Comment: Well, I'm glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 2):

In my searching for a few images to show what I'm capable of right now, I came across a website that provided an answer to this question.

**Credit to Dani Winks Flexibility**

[The ultimate bridge pose progression guide](https://www.daniwinksflexibility.com/bendy-blog/the-ultimate-bridge-pose-progression-guide)

[Pushing up into a bridge: progression](https://www.daniwinksflexibility.com/bendy-blog/pushing-up-into-a-bridge-progression)

---

*Recap of stretches that progress to bridge:*

For Tight Pecs: Elbow on the Wall Chest Stretch

For Tight Lats: Puppy Pose

Wide Arm Strap Pulses

Wide Arm Block Pulses

Childs Pose Arm Lifts

Low Cobra Arm Lifts

Puppy Pose Resist-Relax

Wall Elbow Block Push-Ups

Down Dog Push Ups (Wide Elbows)

Down Dog Push Ups (Narrow Elbows)

Tabletop Reaches

Pushing Up Into Headstand Bridge

Back-Supported Bridge Push Up

Headstand Bridge Push Up

[image]